# Writing an R-function that works with multiple existing dataframes

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm working on a R-Script where I have to create multiple variables for multiple existing dataframes. For example: I got the three dataframes AAA, BBB and CCC, and each one of them has a column named "height". I would like to get this:

```
AAA_Skal <- mean(AAA$height) / 6
BBB_Skal <- mean(BBB$height) / 6
CCC_Skal <- mean(CCC$height) / 6
```

without actually writing a entire line of code for each dataframe. (The reason for this is that I got more than just 3 dataframes and I have to proceed a lot of code with them).

What I tried is the following:

```
dfs <- c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")

Skal <- function(x) {
sprintf("%s_Skal", dfs[x]) <- mean(sprintf("%s_$height", dfs[x])) / 6
}
```

I should then be able to type Skal(1) to get

```
AAA_Skal <- mean(AAA$height) / 6
```

First I thought it isnt working because sprintf gives "AAA" as an output, with quotation marks. So I tried as.name(sprintf()), but it doesent work either. I hope someone can help me on this issue, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `assign` and `get`

```
AAA <- data.frame(x = letters[1:10], height = rnorm(10))
BBB <- data.frame(y = sample(20:60, 10), height = rnorm(10, 5))
CCC <- data.frame(z = rbinom(10, 5, .2), height = rnorm(10, 50))

dfs <- c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")

x <- 1
assign(sprintf("%s_Skal", dfs[x]), mean(get(dfs[x])$height) / 6)
AAA_Skal
## [1] -0.02807432
```

But I would recommend storing your `data.frames` in a list so you can do something like

```
l <- list(AAA, BBB, CCC)
sapply(l, function(x) mean(x$height) / 6 )
## [1] -0.02807432  0.84785430  8.38655123
```

Comment: Dear @JakeBurkhead Maybe could it get the same result using `lapply(l, function(x) mean(x$height) / 6 )` what is the difference between `lapply()` and `sapply()`

Comment: @Duck `lapply` will return a list of length 1 numeric vectors (try it out and see!). `sapply` tries to coerce its output into a vector or matrix and names it output, `lapply` will always return a list. `sapply(..., simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)` is equivalent to `lapply`. See `?sapply` for more info.

Comment: Ok @JakeBurkhead `sapply()` is more practical than `lapply()` and it gives me a more clean solution than lapply that gives a list as result.